# Cannot load compressed Kernel module?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, mouse, hid

I tried to load "hid-a4tech," but I got error the messages below:

> [net_client@netarchwork ~]$ modprobe hid-a4tech modprobe: FATAL:
> Module hid-a4tech not found in directory
> /lib/modules/4.18.7-arch1-1-ARCH
>
> [net_client@netarchwork ~]$ sudo insmod
> /lib/modules/4.18.9-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-a4tech.ko.xz
> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module
> /lib/modules/4.18.9-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-a4tech.ko.xz : Invalid module format
>
> [net_client@netarchwork ~]$ ls
> /lib/modules/4.18.9-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/hid/ | grep a4tech
> hid-a4tech.ko.xz

So, form the errors above `modprode` couldn't load compressed module and `insmod` was unable too! How can be this module loaded?

Comment: Your installed kernel and running kernel are different (4.18.7 v 4.18.9): that is your problem.